# How do I cut a dataframe using pandas in flask?

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I'm doing a school project to display data analysis in a website using pandas and flask. 
I have a csv file of terror around the world and I'm trying to cut from the dataframe only the terror that happened in Greece so I tried to do this and it and it always displaying me a blank dataframe
Here is Some screenshots and pieces of code: 

The code from my views.py:

```
df = pd.read_csv('static/Data/GlobalTerror.csv')).head()
df = df[(df['Country'] == 'Greece')]
raw_data_table = df.to_html(classes='table table-hover')

 return render_template(
        'dataModel.html',
        raw_data_table=raw_data_table,
        title='Data Models',
        year=datetime.now().year,
        message='Links to the data'
```

The code from the HTML file:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<html>
  <body>
    {{ raw_data_table | safe}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot from Jupyter that I do the same thing and it works:

[image]

Does anybody know this problem and know how to solve it?

Comment: raw_data_terror_table <--- can you show us the whole code. Can't see this defined in your code.

Comment: Print to yourself raw_data_table and check its content

Comment: You are calling `head` before filtering on *Greece* records. If *Greece* does not show up in first 5 rows the filtered data frame will be blank.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Parfait](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422451/parfait)!
This was the solution!

*"You are calling head before filtering on Greece records. If Greece does not show up in first 5 rows the filtered data frame will be blank."* – [Parfait](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422451/parfait)